# Yeoman tutorial missing styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to get through [this getting started tutorial](http://yeoman.io/codelab/index.html) provided by Yeoman.  It is supposed to be styled with bootstrap css, but the initial launch looks like this:

[image]

I'm new at this, but I think this indicates missing CSS.  The index file starts out like this...

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="mytodoApp">
...
```

The stuff in comments, like `build:css`, does that mean I'm supposed to do something on the command line?  The tutorial doesn't mention anything.

The main.css file looks okay, and looks like it contains CSS things that I need, like `.jumbotron { ... }`.  Also, the bower directory contains a "bootstrap" subdirectory, with lots of promising looking CSS, but the tutorial doesn't mention anything about this either.  The tutorial seems to assume that [the first launch should look great already, here...](http://yeoman.io/codelab/preview-inbrowser.html)

I'm sure I've done all of the steps to this point.  Any idea what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [github issue](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman.github.io/issues/479) solved my problem.  The answer waaaay at the bottom suggests to do the following:

```
$ bower install --save bootstrap#3.3.4
```

and then

```
$ grunt wiredep
```

It would be an even better answer if it explained what those things mean.